# MySQL: delete all rows not just updated

Tags: php, mysql, forms

The idea is that after looping over a submission form, all rows not just updated by the form are deleted from the database.

Is there an elegant MySQL declaration for something like that?

Comment: One option would be to, while in a transaction, delete all rows pre-emptively, and insert the 'updated' rows from the form.

Answer (score 2):

No. Store the PKs and use NOT IN after to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting before hand is dangerous; what if a user closes the browser? Aid storing primary keys is an option. The simplest ended up being this:

1) Set all matching row dates to something like Jan 1 1970.
2) Submit form, including current time in updated rows.
3) Delete all rows with old date.

Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a timestamp column in the table. all rows that are updated would have the current timestamp. and then you can run a delete query selecting all rows that would have their timestamps less than the approximate time when you updated the table. not a full-proof solution though.

another would be to set some columns value while updating, and later deleting the rows whose column value did not get updated

Comment: To elaborate on this, you could have an int field: updated, then UPDATE table SET updated=0;  UPDATE table set new_values="", updated=1; DELETE FROM table WHERE updated=0;

Answer (score 0):

How about a reversed condition?

Update tbl set this = that where col = 'something';
Delete from tbl where col != 'something';