# MySQL INSERT VS UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve around 60,000+ MySQL Records from a partner's server and save it to my database. My Script needs to do this 3X a day (60K+ X 3)

Which one is better and faster

```
DELETE ALL Records from my DB -> Retrieve Records from Partner DB -> Insert Records to my DB

OR

Retrieve records from partner DB -> Update my DB records (if exist) / INSERT (if not exist)
```

NOTE : if UPDATE, I need to update all the fields of the record

Comment: The former is likely to be quicker - deleting all records is probably best implemented by TRUNCATE table or similar...

Comment: It might depends on how many changes there are between two requests.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the 2nd one

> Retrieve records from partner DB -> Update my DB records (if exist) / INSERT (if not exist)

Deleting is a costly operation, esp. when u have a case of 60k+ records and considering that schema remains same overtime only the values change.

Also, consider it from this point of view that, *if updating*, then not all values may not need to be updated, only *some* of them....so this is a comparatively cheaper than deleting and again writing the values which might even contain some of the same values which you just deleted! :)

Don't just consider it from `delet`ing point of view, also consider that you have to *`Update`* the DB too....what would you prefer, always updating 60k+ values or less than that....

Comment: I disagree - If he's deleting all the records, he can just truncate or even drop the table(s). Its a cheap operation.

Comment: @NoobEditor. Even if the Delete is just a simple DELETE * FROM tablehere ? (No need to search for records one by one)

Comment: @vogomatix : what about `updat` ing the DB, `delete` is not the only operation to consider here?? :)

Comment: After the delete, he's just inserting all the records without any need to check whether they exist. This too is cheaper to do than a UPDATE/INSERT (REPLACE) operation

Answer (score 0):

Acording to my opinion, second approach will be more faster than the first one. Because if recoeds already exist then it will skip that record from insertion.

Comment: I must disagree on this one. Cause for mysql to know, it'll have to search if the record actually exist.

Comment: But Still I need to update all the fields of that record

Comment: yes surely it will, and if the record exist it will not insert that record. That will be time saving for the user.

Comment: And how do you update ? if the product size has changed for example

Comment: @sup. Yes but most records are usually changed everyday

Comment: Alternative answer -Why copy the entire dataset from your partners server at all - just open another connection and query the partner server when you need it.

Comment: @vogomatix : assuming OP is *backup* and partner is a *production* server!! :)

Comment: If the OP is a backup server then he should set up proper database replication :-)

Comment: @vogomatix I cant do  copy of the database. While inserting the records I need to add data (1 or 2 fields) not existing on partner DB.

Answer (score 0):

The two operation sequences you've proposed are **NOT equivalent**. 
The second operation sequence does NOT delete the rows which were removed from the partner DB, while the first sequence does delete them.

MySQL provides [`REPLACE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), which does effectively the same as your second sequence and will *probably* be the fastest one. Benchmark your code to be sure.

Comment: If I use replace the records that was deleted from partner DB will also removed from my DB without doing any test / search?

Comment: No, they won't be deleted! Neither will they if you use UPDATE+INSERT (your second sequence).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8915385/2170192) may also be interesting to you.

Comment: If Replace and Update will have the same effect, Its still better to use the first sequence (Delete ALL then Insert)?